# Javascript regular expression replace with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help in writing regular expression replace function which can convert the following string:

```
The product was added by user-345 and approved by admin-91 a week ago.
```

and the output should be link this:

```html
The product was added by <a href="user/345">user-345</a> and approved by <a href="admin/345">admin-91</a> a week ago.
```

Comment: We'd love to help.  Where are you stuck?  What criteria will be used to create these links?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. Very new to regex.

Comment: @Computerer you sure?

Comment: user-(some number) links to user/(somenumber) and admin-(some number) links to admin/(some number)

Comment: @AmitJoki I mean not sure ;)

Comment: @Computerer it would suffice I suppose `str.replace(/(\w+)-(\d+)/g, '<a href="$1/$2">$1-$2</a>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a string replace. If 'user' and 'admin' are your only keywords, you could replace

```
/(user|admin)-(\d+)/g
```

with

```
<a href="$1/$2">$1-$2</a>
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/jO6fC0/1

Comment: regex101.com is nice :) thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple task.  You want to match either `admin` or `user`, then a number.  For that, you can do:

```
/(user|admin)-(\d+)/
```

Then using backreferences you can replace the matched string with a link.  Something like this:

```
str = str.replace(/(user|admin)-(\d+)/g, '<a href="$1/$2">$&</a>');
```

Comment: What is $&? It does not work for me!

Comment: Oops, My bad! It works :)

Comment: @Computerer: `$&` is the *full* string that matched the regex.